# Why does the threshold apply to the MUST_SIGNAL phase in revised BIP 8 (lot=true)? Why doesn't it enforce 100 percent signaling?

Tags: soft-fork, taproot, activation-mechanism, bip8-version-bits

[BIP 8](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0008.mediawiki#new-consensus-rules) states that:

> During the MUST_SIGNAL phase, if (2016 - threshold) blocks in the
> retarget period have already failed to signal, any further blocks that
> fail to signal are invalid.

Why doesn't it enforce 100 percent signaling during the MUST_SIGNAL phase rather than merely the threshold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nickler answered this on IRC.

> In a mixed network, the rules can become active, but in two separate chains because lot=true nodes will reject blocks from the lot=false chain which doesn't require 100% signaling.

The MUST_SIGNAL [phase](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0008.mediawiki#state-transitions) (when lot=true) overlaps with the last two weeks (2016 blocks) of the STARTED phase (when lot=false). In the case that the threshold of miners signaling is met (but not 100 percent of miners signaling) during these two weeks you don't want to create a chain split between lot=true and lot=false nodes for no reason. If MUST_SIGNAL enforced 100 percent signaling and there wasn't 100 percent signaling during this period you would get a chain split between lot=true and lot=false nodes.